# Does the main function of a C program ever reclaim the stack?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow, calling-convention

I am working through the OverTheWire wargames and one of my exploits overwrites the return address of `main` with the address of `system`. I have then used the fact that at the point `main` returns, `esp` is still pointing at one of my local variables and hence I can fill it with the command I want `system` to run (e.g. `sh;#`).

My confusion comes from that I thought functions in C reclaim the stack before returning and hence at the point the return address is called the stack pointer would be pointing at the return address rather than at the local variables. However, my exploit works so it seems that my stack pointer is pointing at the local variables when the return address is called.

The main thing I have noticed about this particular challenge compared to others is that it calls `exit(0)` at the end, instead of just ending, so the assembly doesn't end with `leave`, which may be the reason for this behaviour.

I haven't included the actual code since it's quite long and I was hoping there was a general explanation for what I am seeing, but please let me know if the assembly would be useful.

Comment: Yes, you got that right. Calling `exit` terminates the program before `main` has a chance to do its cleanup things.

Comment: Ah awesome, do you happen to know where I can read about this? Or should I just step through the assembly for `exit` to see it?

Comment: It would not be something in exit, it would be in the operating system.  The operating system allocated the memory for the program when the program exits the operating system deallocates the memory, all of it program, data, stack...

Comment: exit should just lead up to the system call to the operating system...maybe it does other cleanup like close all files and things it can manage or maybe the OS does that.

Comment: an alternate path would be returning from main rather than exit and in that case disassemble the program and look at the main entrance and exit and should like any other function because for the most part that is all main is.  It should clean itself up, the bootstrap in that case would take the return from main and call exit.

Comment: Well in my case `main` allocated the space on the stack for its local variables, not the kernal, but from what I can see it doesn't reclaim it itself. When `exit` is called is the responsibility for reclaiming `main`'s stack handed to the kernal then?

Comment: @Dippynark, so mm, you're saying that you overwrite the return address of `main` and get `system()` to be called even though `main` never returns since the program exits through calling `exit()`? That's the part here that I'm confused about.

Comment: Yeah that's what I believe to be happening, but it's likely that I'm just ignorant about the whole process. It seems that I'm overwriting the return address of `main` with the address of `system` and then at some point (maybe during `exit` or after) that address is called. At the point it is called, `esp` is still pointing at `main`'s local variables and hence I can fill them with the command I want to run. This is different from any other function I've disassembled where the stack is reclaimed before the return address is called, which is why I'm confused

Comment: the call to `exit` should be something like `push 0; call exit;`, it shouldn't matter much what there was in the stack at that point since it has no reason to use anything else, I think. Unless there's something above `main` in the stack that the C library uses in `exit`. Is there any part of the code you could show?

Comment: Ah sorrrrry, I went to copy the code and worked out why I'm confused, for some reason the compiler hasn't put the local variables on the stack in the order they're defined, so I'm actually overflowing into a function pointer, so I need to work out why that rearrangement is happening, but that's a different question. Thanks for all the useful comments

Comment: space is allocated for the program before it is launched, before loaded into ram to be run.  when you exit properly that space is freed, none of this can be visible within the program, not possible.  stack space is just one small part of it...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ( void )
{
    printf("hello\n");
    return(0);
}
```

the interesting relevant parts.

```
0000000000400430 <main>:
  400430:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400434:   bf d4 05 40 00          mov    $0x4005d4,%edi
  400439:   e8 c2 ff ff ff          callq  400400 <puts@plt>
  40043e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400440:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400444:   c3                      retq   
  400445:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40044c:   00 00 00 
  40044f:   90                      nop



0000000000400450 <_start>:
  400450:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  400452:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  400455:   5e                      pop    %rsi
  400456:   48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  400459:   48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  40045d:   50                      push   %rax
  40045e:   54                      push   %rsp
  40045f:   49 c7 c0 c0 05 40 00    mov    $0x4005c0,%r8
  400466:   48 c7 c1 50 05 40 00    mov    $0x400550,%rcx
  40046d:   48 c7 c7 30 04 40 00    mov    $0x400430,%rdi
  400474:   e8 97 ff ff ff          callq  400410 <__libc_start_main@plt>
  400479:   f4                      hlt    
  40047a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

For the most part there is nothing special about main nor printf, etc these are just functions that conform to the calling convention.  As re-asked SO questions will show sometimes the compiler will add extra stack or other calls when it sees a main() that it doesnt otherwise.  but still it is a function that needs to conform to the calling convention.  As seen in this case where the stack pointer is put back where it was found.

Before an operating system (Linux, Windows, MacOS, etc) can even think about running a program it needs to allocate some space for that program and tag that memory for that program in some way depending on the features of the processor and the OS, etc.  Then you load the program from whatever media, and launch it at the binary file specified and/or well known entry point.  A clean exit of the program will cause the operating system to free that memory, which the .text, .data, .bss and stack are the trivial/obvious ones that just go away as their memory just goes away.  Other items that may have been allocated and associated with this program, open files, runtime allocated (not stack) memory, etc can/should also be freed, depends on the design of the os and/or the C library as to how that happens.

In the above case we see the bootstrap calls main and main returns then hlt is hit which this is an application not kernel code so that should cause a trap that causes the OS to clean up.  An explicit exit() should be no different than a printf() or puts() or fopen() or any other function that ultimately makes one or more syscalls to the operating system.  All that you can possibly find for these types of operating systems (Linux, Windows, MacOS) is the syscall.  The release of memory happens outside the program as the program does not have control over it, would be a chicken and egg problem, program frees mmu tables that is using to free mmu tables...

compile and disassemble the object for main rather than the whole program

```
0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   4:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  e <main+0xe>
   e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  10:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  14:   c3                      retq
```

no surprise there same as before, all we needed to see to understand that the stack was cleaned up before return.  and that main is not special:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int notmain ( void )
{
    printf("hello\n");
    return(0);
}

0000000000000000 <notmain>:
   0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
   4:   bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  e <notmain+0xe>
   e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  10:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  14:   c3                      retq
```

Now if you are asking if there is an exit() within main then sure it wont hit the return point in main so the stack pointer is offset by whatever amount.  but if main calls some function and that function calls some function then that function calls exit() then the stack pointer is left at the stack frame point of function number two plus whatever the call (this is an x86) plus the exit() stack frame adds to it.   You cannot simply assume that when exit() is called, if it is called, what the stack pointer is pointing at.  You would have to examine the disassembly around that call to exit() plus the exit() code and anything it calls, to figure this out.

Comment: there is nothing special about exit() either it is just a function if compiled it conforms to the calling convention as well and might have a stack frame, etc, if asm then they did what they did, depends on the OS and library you are linking with.  So no reason to assume that you can examine the stack pointer on the exit() call and make any assumptions as to what is above/below it.  Compiler and compiler options play a big role in this as well, compiled functions are always cleaned up but what is actually on the stack if anything is not consistent.